# Model binding MVC for multiple values of properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

If I have a sample class say X:

```
public class X
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm getting multiple values for `Id` and `Name` from a function:

```
var Xgroups = await client.Groups.GetGroupsAsync();
```

And `Id` and `Name` can be selected from `Xgroups` as follows:

```
foreach (var group in Xgroups.Value)
{ 
    ids.Add(group.Id); //ids is list of id
    names.Add(group.Name); //names is list name
}
```

How can I bind these values to the model?  Should I use lists like I did in the above lines of code? How can I achieve this?

```
var xgroups = new X() { Ids = ids, Names = names };
```

Comment: You need to create a `List<X>` and add an object of `X` to that (with Id and Name property values filled in)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is the UI pattern you are enabling?  Table?  Grid?  Dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Shyju, you can dynamically create a list containing X classes:

```
var list = new List<X>();
foreach (var group in Xgroups.Value)
{
    list.Add(new X
        {
            Id = group.Id,
            Name = group.Name
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Answers with just code unaccompanied by explanation are rarely upvoted as often as those with an explanation.

Comment: Minimalism as a way of life ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
       This is converting your response from wcf service to List of class type 
        X. 
       var results =  Xgroups.Value.Select(a=>new X{ Id = a.Id,Name = a.Name 
        }).ToList();

    I would give a proper name to the model rather than X like  Person, 
     GroupPerson.
```

Comment: Answers with just code unaccompanied by explanation are rarely upvoted as often as those with an explanation.

Comment: Seems that the OP uses X for simplicity here.